# How do I run a regression conditional on a specific id?

Tags: r

I have panel data, and I am trying to run a quantile regression model for only specific countries within the panel. So I have a country indicator column going from 1 to 10, but want to run the regression for say countries 3, 6, and 10.

For the quantile regressions I use the package `quantreg`.

I tried the `foreach` command

```
foreach(data$country=cbind(3,6,10)) %do% rq(data$y ~ data$x, tau = .5)
```

But this gives the error `Error: unexpected '=' in "foreach(data$country="`. Then I thought maybe using `==` might work, but this gives the error

```
Error in eval(a, envir = extra, enclos = obj$evalenv) : 
  dims [product 3] do not match the length of object [6916]
In addition: Warning message:
In data$country == cbind(3, 6, 10) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

I have also tried with a `for` loop, to no avail. The problem seems to arise because I am trying to run the regression y ~ x by country id for specific countries.

Comment: `foreach(data$country %in%cbind(3,6,10)) %do% rq(y ~ x, data, tau = .5)` ?

Comment: Thanks. But unfortunately this does not work. This oddly just repeats the same regression (including all data) 1000 times before stopping. This to me makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with **data.table**. A good place to start learning the package is [here](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/articles/datatable-intro.html).

Please have a look at the code below to check if this is of any help.

```r
library(data.table)
library(plm)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'plm'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:data.table':
#> 
#>     between
library(quantreg)
#> Loading required package: SparseM
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'SparseM'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     backsolve
library(foreach)

data("Crime")

setDT(Crime)

setkey(Crime, county)
to_retain = c( 1, 3, 5 )
to_model = Crime[ .(to_retain) ]

# version with plain for
models = vector("list", length(to_retain))
for ( i_county in seq_along( to_retain ) ) {
  models[[ i_county ]] = rq(prbarr ~ lcrmrte + taxpc, tau = .5, 
                            data = to_model[ county == to_retain[ i_county ] ] ) 
}
models
#> [[1]]
#> Call:
#> rq(formula = prbarr ~ lcrmrte + taxpc, tau = 0.5, data = to_model[county == 
#>     to_retain[i_county]])
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>  (Intercept)      lcrmrte        taxpc 
#>  0.455727325  0.007160880 -0.003789611 
#> 
#> Degrees of freedom: 7 total; 4 residual
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> Call:
#> rq(formula = prbarr ~ lcrmrte + taxpc, tau = 0.5, data = to_model[county == 
#>     to_retain[i_county]])
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>  (Intercept)      lcrmrte        taxpc 
#>  0.134768608 -0.022828915 -0.001766258 
#> 
#> Degrees of freedom: 7 total; 4 residual
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> Call:
#> rq(formula = prbarr ~ lcrmrte + taxpc, tau = 0.5, data = to_model[county == 
#>     to_retain[i_county]])
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)     lcrmrte       taxpc 
#> 2.610536425 0.485028585 0.003379401 
#> 
#> Degrees of freedom: 7 total; 4 residual

# version with sequential foreach
models_2 = foreach( i_count = seq_along( to_retain ), .packages = c("data.table", "quantreg") ) %do% {
  rq(prbarr ~ lcrmrte + taxpc, tau = .5, 
     data = to_model[ county == to_retain[ i_county ] ] ) 
} 

models_2
#> [[1]]
#> Call:
#> rq(formula = prbarr ~ lcrmrte + taxpc, tau = 0.5, data = to_model[county == 
#>     to_retain[i_county]])
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)     lcrmrte       taxpc 
#> 2.610536425 0.485028585 0.003379401 
#> 
#> Degrees of freedom: 7 total; 4 residual
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> Call:
#> rq(formula = prbarr ~ lcrmrte + taxpc, tau = 0.5, data = to_model[county == 
#>     to_retain[i_county]])
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)     lcrmrte       taxpc 
#> 2.610536425 0.485028585 0.003379401 
#> 
#> Degrees of freedom: 7 total; 4 residual
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> Call:
#> rq(formula = prbarr ~ lcrmrte + taxpc, tau = 0.5, data = to_model[county == 
#>     to_retain[i_county]])
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)     lcrmrte       taxpc 
#> 2.610536425 0.485028585 0.003379401 
#> 
#> Degrees of freedom: 7 total; 4 residual
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>